# grunt-karma debug unminified sources

Tags: debugging, gruntjs, karma-runner

I remember that at some point in the past I could actually debug my tests with Chrome Dev Tools and go into my unminified sources.

I'm not sure if this is a configuration option that was changed but now whenever I try to debug my tests using Chrome I see only the minified sources.

Is there an option I need to set to see the unminified sources?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution to this that does not involve losing coverage data!

Based on this guide for [Debugging Karma Unit Tests](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/debugging-karma-unit-tests/), I came up with the following, which works in IntelliJ:

```
var sourcePreprocessors = 'coverage';

var isDebugMode = function () {
    return process.argv.some(function (argument) {
        return argument === '--debug';
    });
};

var hasNoCoverage = function () {
    return !(process.argv.some(function (argument) {
        return argument.includes("coverage");
    }));
};

if (isDebugMode() || hasNoCoverage()) {
    console.log("Not generating coverage.");
    sourcePreprocessors = '';
}

config.set({
    ...
    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
        "WebRoot/js/**/*.js": sourcePreprocessors
    },
    ...
});
```

---

**NOTE:**

Per info mentioned [here](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-coverage/issues/149), adding the following to your `karma.conf.js` (or however you are configuring Karma) should disable minification:

```
coverageReporter: {
  instrumenterOptions: {
    istanbul: { noCompact: true }
  }
}
```

**However**, this does not remove the coverage data, and the source files still end up getting mangled up:

```
__cov_SNsw2QFfQtMZHyIEO9CT1A.s['74']++;
my.toPercentageString = function (value) {
    __cov_SNsw2QFfQtMZHyIEO9CT1A.f['18']++;
    __cov_SNsw2QFfQtMZHyIEO9CT1A.s['75']++;
    return numbro(value).format('0.0%');
};
__cov_SNsw2QFfQtMZHyIEO9CT1A.s['76']++;
```

---

Comment: link to the karma guide is broken, and now asks to buy the domain

Answer (score 9):

Disabling the `preprocessors` Karma configuration in the `Gruntfile.js` did it.

```
var karmaConfig = {
...

  preprocessors: {
    // 'js/**/*.js': 'coverage'
    },
  reporters: ['spec', 'coverage'],
  colors: true,
  singleRun: false,
  usePolling: true,  

...
```

Comment: What is causing the minification? Is it Instanbul? Why does removing preprocessors eliminate minification?

Comment: Honestly I don't know. Wha happened is that I went through my commit history and I found that the preprocessors were added so I tested without them and it turns out that did it. I guess you could go through Karma's repo and try to figure it out but I don't know if you want to do that.

Comment: Thank you! This was driving me nuts, couldn't figure out why IntelliJ wasn't stopping at breakpoints in the source files, but did stop at breakpoints in the tests. This fixed it!

Answer (score 2):

Disabling `preprocessors` (like @pgpb.padilla mentioned) unfortunately disables code coverage (istanbul) if that is something you use. I found that only way to disable obfuscation is to run separately without `coverage` reporter i.e. `karma start karma.config.js --reporters progress` and then separately for the build include the coverage `karma start karma.config.js --reporters progress,coverage`